# Get author and publication from website using JS - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the author name from a website using a chrome extension. I was wondering if there was any outside js libraries that are compatible with chrome extensions that I could use to grab this info without having to manually code an HTML parser which is way above my skill level. All I want to do is be able to use a content script to grab the author’s name of a news article, like CNN. I’ve heard of external node.js packages like metascraper.js, but I can’t figure out how to use them with a chrome extension. Thanks!!

Comment: Doesn’t a Chrome extension have access to the DOM? Why would you need an HTML parser…?

Comment: Questions seeking library recommendations are off-topic here, anyway - please familiarize yourself with the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Maybe parser is the wrong term. Again, sorry, my skill level and knowledge is very low and I’ve been researching this for several days trying to find a solution and just wanted to see if anyone with more experience could point me in the right direction. I know I can access the DOM using the chrome extension, but I also know that not every article stores the author name the same way (or so I have read), so just targeting one spot on the DOM has a good chance of returning nothing?

Comment: From the way you described what you're trying to achieve, yeah - your DOM selector will only ever work for a specific website (and luckily others built on top of the same template). Otherwise, it might indeed return nothing, or even a false positive. The surefire way to go about it is to store different selectors for each website (and possibly page). Another idea would be to take a look at the [W3C Accessibility Standards](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/#atag) and target the patterns therein - it's probably safe to assume these websites are likely to take accessibility seriously.